# Asp.Net "AccessViolationException was unhandled" error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, exception, odp.net

When i installed Oracle 12.x data client althrough previously installed Oracle 11.x on my computer and i run to project i have got this error `"AccessViolationException was unhandled. Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"`. Actually this exception does not prevent normally program flow (program fired properly) but the program usually throws exception. How can i solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check concurrent access and/or whether both or only the v12 oracle driver is loaded. It seems to be a concurrency like problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am using Oracle 11.x client in my project and dll reference point 11.x client's physical path. what's kind of concurrency mistake?